# Generic object pool class using Spinlock/Monitor

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, locking

I've written the following object pool class, and because this is my first encounter with synchronization primitives, I need reinsurance from an expert that this code is safe. I've tested it myself using 100 threads on a pool with a capacity of 4, and an expansion limit of 128, it appeared to be fully functional so far.

The class uses two locking methods, a custom spinlock using `SpinWait`, and `Monitor`. A spinlock is invoked for all short, straightforward operations. Additionally, `Monitor` is used in cases where all objects are already in use by other threads. Because it is unknown when the object will be returned to the pool, a spinlock would be the worst option.

I did my best to ensure the greatest efficiency possible, so I'm also interested in how this class competes against .NET's equivalent types to solve this problem. I don't even know what the equivalent types are, I've noticed types such as `ConcurrentBag`, but they didn't make sense compared to the my standard object pool design. Additional insights on performance are highly appreciated.

Note that any function safeguards are missing by intent.

```
internal class Pool<T> where T : class
{
    private int capacity;
    private int expansionLimit;
    private int unitPos;
    private int waitUnitPos;
    private int waitCount;
    private int lockState;
    private object lockObj;
    private object expansionLockObj;
    private T[] units;
    private Func<T> unitFactory;

    public Pool(int capacity, int expansionLimit, Func<T> unitFactory)
    {
        this.expansionLimit = expansionLimit;
        this.lockObj = new object();
        this.expansionLockObj = new object();
        this.unitFactory = unitFactory;

        Init(capacity);
    }

    public T Fetch()
    {
        T unit;

        Lock();
        unit = (unitPos != capacity) ? unit = units[unitPos++] : (capacity < expansionLimit ? Expand() : Wait());
        Unlock();

        return unit;
    }

    public void Store(T unit)
    {
        Lock();

        if (waitCount == 0)
        {
            units[--unitPos] = unit;
        }
        else
        {
            Pulse(unit);
        }

        Unlock();
    }

    private T Expand()
    {
        T unit = null;

        bool lockTaken = false;

        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(expansionLockObj, ref lockTaken);

            if (!lockTaken)
            {
                Unlock();
                Monitor.Enter(expansionLockObj, ref lockTaken);
                Lock();
            }

            if (unitPos != this.capacity)
            {
                unit = units[unitPos++];
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.capacity == expansionLimit)
                {
                    unit = Wait();
                }
                else
                {
                    Unlock();

                    int capacity = this.capacity;
                    int newCapacity = capacity * 2;

                    if (newCapacity > expansionLimit)
                    {
                        newCapacity = expansionLimit;
                    }

                    T[] newUnits = new T[newCapacity];

                    for (int i = capacity; i < newCapacity; i++)
                    {
                        newUnits[i] = unitFactory.Invoke();
                    }

                    Lock();

                    Array.Copy(units, 0, newUnits, 0, capacity);
                    units = newUnits;
                    this.capacity = newCapacity;
                    unit = units[unitPos++];
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(expansionLockObj);
            }
        }

        return unit;
    }

    private T Wait()
    {
        waitCount++;

        lock (lockObj)
        {
            Unlock();
            Monitor.Wait(lockObj);
        }

        Lock();

        return units[--waitUnitPos];
    }

    private void Pulse(T unit)
    {
        waitCount--;
        units[waitUnitPos++] = unit;

        lock (lockObj)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(lockObj);
        }
    }

    private void Lock()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lockState, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            SpinLock();
        }
    }

    private void SpinLock()
    {
        SpinWait spinWait = new SpinWait();

        do
        {
            spinWait.SpinOnce();
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lockState, 1, 0) != 0);
    }

    private void Unlock()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref lockState, 0);
    }

    private void Init(int capacity)
    {
        T[] units = new T[capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            units[i] = unitFactory.Invoke();
        }

        this.units = units;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review! Hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's good to see that you used dedicated lock objects `lockObj` and `expansionLockObj`. A minor improvement would be that those can be marked as `readonly`.
2. I find the locking and unlocking processes quite hard to follow. It is not easy to see when what gets locked for which purpose due to the combination of using standard locks and the use of `Interlocked` state guards.
3. I'm pretty sure that the pool will be left in a bad state should the provided unit factory throw (for example triggered by a `Fetch` triggering an `Expand`) due to the `Lock(); dostuff(); Unlock();` pattern (if `dostuff();` throws you're in trouble). Probably not extremely likely but a potential issue.

---

Regarding the performance: I hacked a version together based on the standard [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which turned out to be about three times slower however the code is vastly simpler and shorter (Note: I added an interface to make testing easier):

```
internal interface IObjectPool<T>
{
    T Fetch();
    void Store(T item);
}

internal class Pool2<T> : IObjectPool<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _Objects;
    private int _Capacity;
    private readonly int _Limit;
    private readonly Func<T> _ObjectFactory;
    private readonly object _CapacityLock;

    public Pool2(int initialCapacity, int capacityLimit, Func<T> objectFactory)
    {
        capacityLimit = Math.Max(capacityLimit, initialCapacity);
        _Objects = new BlockingCollection<T>(capacityLimit);
        _Capacity = initialCapacity;
        _Limit = capacityLimit;
        _ObjectFactory = objectFactory;
        _CapacityLock = new object();

        GenerateObjects(initialCapacity);
    }

    private void GenerateObjects(int numberOfObjects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; ++i)
        {
            _Objects.Add(_ObjectFactory.Invoke());
        }
    }

    public T Fetch()
    {
        T item;
        if (!_Objects.TryTake(out item))
        {
            int capacityDifference;
            lock (_CapacityLock)
            {
                int oldCapacity = _Capacity;
                _Capacity = Math.Min(_Capacity * 2, _Limit);
                capacityDifference = _Capacity - oldCapacity;
            }
            if (capacityDifference > 0)
            {
                GenerateObjects(capacityDifference);
            }
            return _Objects.Take();
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void Store(T item)
    {
        if (!_Objects.TryAdd(item))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("More items were returned to the pool than were generated");
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmark code:

```
class Program
{
    const int MaxUsers = 100;
    const int MaxObjects = 10000;
    const int NumIterations = 100;
    static Random _Rand = new Random();
    static Task[] _Users = new Task[MaxUsers];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new Pool<object>(1000, MaxObjects, () => new object());
        var pool2 = new Pool2<object>(1000, MaxObjects, () => new object());
        Benchmark(pool,  "Original Pool");
        Benchmark(pool2, "     New Pool");
    }

    private static void Benchmark(IObjectPool<object> pool, string name)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxUsers; ++i)
        {
            _Users[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UsePool(pool));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(_Users);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static void UsePool(IObjectPool<object> pool)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumIterations; ++i)
        {
            var toConsume = _Rand.Next(1, MaxObjects + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < toConsume; ++j)
            {
                var obj = pool.Fetch();
                pool.Store(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (on my machine):

```
Original Pool: 7055ms
     New Pool: 20676ms
```

So in the end you'll have to decide if simpler code is better (better maintainability, lower chance of bugs, etc.) or if the object pool really is the performance bottleneck.

Comment: Concerning state-safety, I've wrapped the working part of `Fetch` in a finally block so that an unexpected `ThreadAbortException` won't cause trouble for other threads. I agree that the locking logic is not easily perceptible, especially not in the `Expand` method. It didn't have to be difficult if I chose to use a spinlock all the way, but that may be very inefficient during the creation of new units.

Performance is not _really_ worth it to be fair. In any typical case, the operations performed by the fetched object should massively overrule the time taken to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, I suggest you use the `lock` keyword rather than relying on `Monitor`. From the [MSDN page on Monitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Visual Basic SyncLock and C# lock statements use Monitor.Enter to take the lock and Monitor.Exit to release it. The advantage of using the language statements is that everything in the lock or SyncLock block is included in a Try statement. The Try statement has a Finally block to guarantee that the lock is released.

It's just syntactic sugar, but will make your code a lot more concise. As ChrisWue already mentioned, the locking/unlocking logic is not immediately clear. There are many situations in which code maintainability (which derives from readability) is more important than performance. (This may not be one of those situations, but still.)

I would also opt towards using [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructs where possible to minimize the need for locking. I see you are already using CompareExchange, but perhaps you could also use Add() (fetch-and-add) to atomically increment/decrement certain variables, e.g. `unitPos` in `Fetch()`. Again I haven't completely understood your code and I don't know whether this will actually work for your particular scenario, so just take it as a general suggestion.

Comment: By now, I have tested this class in extreme scenarios, and it seems to work flawlessly. Using `Interlocked.Increment` aligns towards lock-free code, which is not a viable option in this class, neither would it be beneficial because a spinlock is rarely necessary. Using the `lock` statement is not an option either, because I need `Monitor.TryEnter`. I can't really elaborate on the necessity of the advanced locking logic, if you care to study it, then I promise you that it will perfectly make sense.